# UNION 2 Tables, (combining them)

Tags: mysql, sql, union

I have Products_A

```
Product_ID Product_Name Price Quantity 
11         MilkA 36     56    3
21         MeatB 123    78    23 
31         SugarA 29    45    333
```

Products_B

```
Product_ID Product_Name Price Quantity 
21         MilkB 63     65    33  
22         MeatB 321    87    4345 
23         SugarB 92    54    232
```

I want Select query like this

```
Product_ID Quantity Quantity*Price
11         36       
21         123
31         29
21         63
22         321
23         92
```

I try

```
SELECT
  Products_A.Quantity,
  Products_B.Quantity,
  Products_A.Quantity * Products_A.Price,
  Products_B.Quantity*Products_B.Price
  FROM products_A,
  products_B;
```

But this looks unformatted. Details

Comment: search for UNION in SQL querying!

Answer (score 2):

If you want results from both tables, you can use an UNION ALL.

```
SELECT
  a.Product_Id as product_Id, 
  a.Quantity, 
  a.Quantity * a.Price as total
FROM Products_A a
UNION ALL
SELECT
  b.Product_Id as product_Id,
  b.Quantity,
  b.Quantity * b.Price as total
FROM Products_B b
```

Comment: Thanks Raphael, you forgot comma in b but this is for future visitors.